# Help with wiring in an old house!

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I have a house built in 1956. I am trying to put in a new LED mirror where there was an old medicine cabinet with florescent lights. The wiring has a black and white coming out of the same tube, but there is a separate white wire off to the side. I got in the crawl space, and it looks like this was the previous owner's attempt at a ground wire. The new mirror has black (hot), white (neutral), and green (ground) wires for the light. Think it's safe to hook the green up to the separate white wire for the ground[image]?

Comment: If you check that the other end is connected to a proper ground, not just wrapped around a 2x4, it is probably safe for you.  I think code does not allow non green/bare wires for use as ground wire, so it will need to be replaced upon inspection and/or your insurance might have reason to refuse any claims.

Comment: Very definitely determine what the other end of that mostly bare other wire is attached to. Also, is it really dirty copper wire or is it aluminum? If it's aluminum, be sure to use the proper connectors for it or you'll end up with one of the horror stories from the 70s. If you use the proper connectors for it, it will serve you well for many more decades.

Comment: No insurance issue with an added ground, if properly connected at the other end it is overkill on size in any case but should be remarked with green.

Comment: Where is the other end of that wire attached to?

Comment: I've read the pros here write about acceptability of retrofitting ground wires to available connection points but I've never seen it in practice.  It would be nice if you posted pictures of what happens at the other end of this wire.  Both to help determine if it is what you think and also to serve as an example of how to do that if it was done properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DrSparks "Think it's safe to hook the green up to the separate white wire for the ground `<picture>` ?" yeah, he got the pic between the question and the question mark...

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit ground is allowed, so you *should* be OK. There are 5 possible issues with that ground wire:

1. It is stranded (though rather thick strands). That is a bit unusual for ground. One of the pros can speak up as to whether that is a code issue or not.
2. It *might* be aluminum. For a bunch of reasons, that would be a problem. However, from the picture it appears that it may be either coated copper (in which case it is fine as long as you have a good connection) or just dirty (also fine, once you clean it off). If it is aluminum then the dissimilar metals problem comes up, but if that is the case then I think there are bigger problems as a single aluminum wire would not normally be installed as a retrofit ground, so that may be an indication of improper installation.
3. Where does it go? It must go back to something connected to the primary ground (i.e., in the main panel). That could be direct, or it could be via another circuit (which is OK). But you need to find out. While technically it may be OK, connection to a copper water pipe is not a great solution here, because plumbing could be changed at some time that would end up leaving the ground disconnected.
4. Color. Grounds are normally bare wire or green. There are exceptions at really large sizes, but that does not apply here. Electrically the color makes no differences (electrons are color-blind), but it does matter for code. From a practical matter, wrapping the exposed white area *and the white area on the other end of the wire where it connects to the building ground* takes care of making sure that the next owner doesn't get confused.
5. Is the ground working? Simplest way to check that is to check for continuity between the ground wire and the neutral (white in the cable) wire. But remember that even if you have continuity, the concerns noted above still apply.

Comment: Very unusual looks to be copper or copper clad. Solid,  stranded, covered or bare are all code compliant but the size ? May not be quite code for white, add some green tape and it just may be legal to 2017 NEC standards depending on size.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that that ground wire is tinned copper. Back in the day they used tinned copper to protect the wire from corrosive action due to the high sulfur content of the rubber insulation. It's possible that the copper that's visible are areas where the tinning has worn.

As for the safety of using this wire as an equipment ground, it really depends. As the other answerer mentioned, you need to verify continuity to the neutral conductor. This is not the greatest test, but short of buying expensive equipment, it's the best you got.

The problem with a fished separate ground wire is that, although it's allowed by code, it does not offer a very low impedance path to the neutral bus in your panel due to the properties of alternating current. It'll probably do it's job, but there's always a risk that there could be a delay in opening the circuit breaker due to ground impedance, and even the most brief split second delay is enough to create enough fireworks to ignite combustible materials.

A solution in this case may be to use a lighting fixture that is completely non-metallic, thus not requiring a ground wire.